# Get parameter, passed via the link in PHP

Tags: php, http, http-get, superglobals

I get variable from `http://localhost/match?id=1` via code:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $id = secure($id);
} else {
    echo "error";
    die();
}
```

And I get the error from my else statement. How to get the parameter, passed via the link?

Comment: If you're trying that through a browser `....?id=1` will make it a GET request, and thus you won't see anything in `$_POST`.
If you need to do a POST request, you [can use curl](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) to test it with.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) for more details on GET vs POST.

Comment: Also, in case you simply don't care if it's a GET or POST request, you can use `$_REQUEST['id']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id = secure($id);
} else {
    echo "error";
    die();
}
```

Params, passed throught the link, are accessable trough the `$_GET` superglobal.

[Info about $_GET on php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php).

[Some explanations about $_GET vs $_POST on w3schools.com.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: This fixes the symptom but not necessarily the problem :)

Answer (score -1):

use POST if you get data from form. and GET if you get data by link. in your case it is link

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) { ** this POST should be GET because you have http://localhost/match?id=1
```